# Double margin when padding images in HTML email with vspace/hspace

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm coding up an HTML email (ugh!) and because Outlook doesn't respect padding/margins/borders on images I'm using vspace and hspace instead. The image in question can be optionally removed from the template so I need the text which wraps it to also maintain it's own margin. To achieve this I've 'not' applied padding to the box but instead a margin to the H2 and P tags which follow the image.

However in Outlook 2007 and 2010 I end up with a double margin to the left of the image, everything is A OK in Outlook 2013.

Here's my inlined code from Outlook 2010:

```
<td class="box" width="50%" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;background-color:#F8F8F8;vertical-align:top;" >
<img src="http://placehold.it/110x110" width="110" align="left" hspace="10" vspace="10" style="outline-style:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" />
<h2 style="color:#254485 !important;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;font-size:18px;line-height:normal;" >Dolor Bibendum Mollis</h2>
<p style="line-height:normal;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;" >
Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
</td>
```

And here's what I get in Outlook 2007 and 2010 as a result:

[image]

Note the double margin to the left of the image, it seems to apply the hspace but then also inherit the margin applied to the H2 and P tag. :?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using vspace and hspace, wrap the image in a table and apply padding to the table:

```
<table><tr><td class="box" width="50%" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;background-color:#F8F8F8;vertical-align:top;" >
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding:0 10px 10px 0"><img src="http://placehold.it/110x110" width="110" align="left" style="outline-style:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" /></td></tr></table>
<h2 style="color:#254485 !important;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:10px;margin-left:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;font-size:18px;line-height:normal;border-left:10px solid #f8f8f8" >Dolor Bibendum Mollis</h2>
<p style="line-height:normal;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:10px;margin-left:0;" >
Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Was this answer able to help you?